# Is it Possible to Place an AR Object above an AR Object?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, arcore, viro-react

I want to Place an AR object(Chair) onto another AR Object(Platform).
Lets say chair is 3X3 and platform is 6x6 in horizontal plane. I want to ask if it is possible? If Yes, I want to ask if it is possible in which of the following 1. ARCore, 2. ARKit, 3. VIRO React.

I know AR detects real world planes and we can place objects onto it. Also I have seen Videos of APP where in ARCore objects interact with each other.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you do not stack ar object over another ar object. You have to manually create a new type and then you stack the new type over one another.

An example:

You spawn a class Platform and then you detect platform similar way you detect plane, you can use a raycast to do this. Then when you detected the platform, you then offset chair from platform and you spawn it on top of it.